# использование unittest в python для проверки правильности работы класса

Tags: python, ооп, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Нужно проверить класс на правильность работы
в классе есть метод `__add__`.

```py
        def __add__(self, other):
            return [self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z]
```

Как можно проверить правильность его работы с помощью unittest?

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? Или вы хотите, чтобы мы код тестов написали?

Comment: я немного не понимаю как делать тест для метода, у которого в аргументах self и other. мне прикрепить как-то объекты класса или как-нибудь прикрепить необходимые для проверки значения

Comment: Ничего никуда не надо прикреплять. Для каждого тестового случая создаёте по два объекта. Складываете их. И результат с помощью assertEqual сравниваете с ожидаемым результатом.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import unittest
import py

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        o = py.vec_3(1, 2, 3)
        b = py.vec_3(1, 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(o + b, [2, 4, 6])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```